# json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE doesn't get rid of \u0007 character

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, preg-replace

Running the following code should have return me the same character back without coverting it to \u0007 (Replace the x with character \u0007, copy from [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm))
[image]

```
$sample['dd'] = 'x';
$sample = strtolower(json_encode($sample, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

However, I am still getting '\u0007'. Anyone has other ideas?

Here's the sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9034e5d952479b7717e66598d949f895a6f059d4

Comment: `chr(0x07)` isn't multi-byte Unicode which is why I suspect it is printed as \u0007.  `var_dump(json_encode(["€"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ));` does indeed work as expected. I am not sure of any way to prevent escaping of unprintable chars.

Comment: Lets say I give up on escaping them, is there anyway to clean up after json_encode? I tried preg_replace('/\\u\d{4}/', '', $sample), but curiously while it works on sandbox, in my project it will return null

Comment: I would probably run something like `$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $string);` on the input instead of trying to parse the output, but `/\\u[0-9]{4}/` on the output should work.

Comment: The input would be a large, deeply nested JSON, so it would be quite heavy to loop through every single value and keys to do preg_replace. /\\u[0-9]{4}/ should work, and does work on the sandbox, It just doesn't work on my project for some reason (returning null, so some error occurred in preg_replace), I guess I'm out of luck. Anyway, thanks for your help!